# A multiple integral question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, integration, definite-integrals

Proving that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{n \text{ times}}\frac{1}{(x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n)^2+1} \mathrm{d}x_1\cdot\mathrm{d}x_2\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n=1$$

Comment: looks like we can make the use of Taylor's expansion this will turn out to be $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^n}$ which converges to $1$. Nice Question as always (+1)

Comment: @experimentX: thank you! :-) Does Taylor's expansion work here? Let me check that.

Comment: looks like it wasn't Taylor's expansion ... just expansion of $1/(1+x^2)$ haha .. pardon my math vocabulary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ldots\int\limits_{0}^{1}dx_n\ldots dx_1=1
$$
it is enough to show that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ldots\int\limits_{0}^{1}\left(1-\frac{1}{(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)^2+1}\right)dx_n\ldots dx_1=0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ldots\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)^2}{(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)^2+1}dx_n\ldots dx_1=0
$$
Now note that
$$
\begin{align}
0&\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ldots\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)^2}{(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)^2+1}dx_n\ldots dx_1\\
&\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}\ldots\int\limits_{0}^{1}(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n)^2dx_n\ldots dx_1\\
&=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n=0
\end{align}
$$
And the result follows.

Comment: oh, nice!!! I just missed that! (+1) Thanks! :-)

Comment: Not at all$\phantom{}$

Comment: I love the simplicity of your answer!

Comment: Arent you assuming the consequent?

Comment: Assuming what? $\phantom{}$