# A multiple integral question II

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, integration, definite-integrals

We know from the [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311414/a-multiple-integral-question) that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{n \text{ times}}\frac{1}{(x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n)^2+1} \mathrm{d}x_1\cdot\mathrm{d}x_2\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n=1$$

and now I wonder what is $f(n)$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\left(1-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1}_{n \text{ times}}\frac{1}{(x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n)^2+1} \mathrm{d}x_1\cdot\mathrm{d}x_2\cdots\mathrm{d}x_n\right)$$
is finite and then I'd like to find out its precise limit.

Comment: You just make this stuff up, don't you? Some people cook, some crochet, some people have dogs, you sit around and make up problems. Do you get much sunshine? Also, you are evidently more than one person, and exist in separate bodies. You could go out bicycling together.

Comment: Have you tried folk dancing?

Comment: @WillJagy: we can try, can't we? :D

Comment: Now that I think of it, I went to a conference in 2010. An eleven year old girl also gave a talk, a prodigy. I suggested to her mother (attending as chaperone) that soccer might be a nice idea. However, the girl claimed that there was nothing more stupid than running around chasing a ball. Then I said, well maybe something solo, surely there is some sort of traditional dancing for girls (the parents are from India). The mother actually told me "Yes, but she sucks at it." So  maybe you can keep on with the mathematics problems.

Comment: @WillJagy: hehe, interesting.

Comment: making use of my previous comment, i suppose $f(n) = 3^n$

Comment: @WillJagy 13 years back, I wish I were kid like that, now I hope I'll have a kid like that. I feel dumb as bag of hammer.

Comment: @WillJagy: why do say that? You think you spent too much time with math?

Comment: @WillJagy: Anyway, thank you for sharing your thoughts. There are many other nice activities beside doing math and we shouldn't miss them. I understand your point and you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about this but I'll write it anyway.
Writing $\frac{1}{(x_1x_2..x_n)^2+1}$ as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k (x_1x_2..x_n)^{2k}$

We get,

$g(n)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1....\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x_1x_2..x_n)^2+1}dx_1dx_2...dx_n$$=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1....\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k (x_1x_2..x_n)^{2k}dx_1dx_2...dx_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{(2k+1)^n}=\beta(n) $

(The Dirichlet beta function)

Note that $g(n)=1-3^{-n}+o(3^{-n})$

$f(n)=\frac{1}{1-g(n)}=3^n+o(3^n)$ is the function you want.
Taking $f(n)=3^n$

$1\leq\lim_{n\to \infty} 3^n(1-g(n))\leq1-(\frac{3}{5})^n$

and by the squeeze theorem, $\lim{n\to\infty3^n(1-g(n))=1}$

Comment: I like your work so far. Thanks. (+1)

Comment: Wolfram gives the answer in terms of the generalized zeta function, but I don't know if that's helpful.

Comment: I think the function is $\Im(Li_n(i))$

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals Is this enough or is this non-rigorous or incomplete?

Comment: I just realized that something missed in my initial question and my expectations were a bit different. Anyway, I let it this way. Thanks for your work!